# What will be net profit/loss of all people if all people sell a given cryptocurrecy?

Tags: cryptocurrency

In crypto currency is another man loss is someone else gain  and does sum of profit/loss of all person will be zero if every person decide to sell the crypto and no one hold any crypto currency (assume there is no exchange and tax charges) ?

Comment: Sells to who? This isn't an online game, there's no NPC vendor who will always buy anything

Comment: It's possible that people would be unable to trade bitcoins (e.g. because the governments banned them), in which case everyone who paid for them would lose lots of money, while those who previously sold them would be able to keep their profits. Or people could just get bored and delete their Bitcoin wallets, and lose all their money. But neither of these cases exactly match the question: it's impossible for everyone to sell, as opposed to other ways of losing your Bitcoins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a trade to happen you need a buyer and a seller. The above two statements together i.e. if everyone decides to sell the crypto they hold, and no one holds any crypto. doesn't seem possible. Where there is a trade happening you need both buyer and seller. And if all the crypto holders decide to sell then there must be new crypto holders who are willing to buy.